# C# ZedGraph set yaxis max to default after setting a custom value

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Afternoon all,

So I have a application which uses a zedGraphControl to graph out some data that the application collections but I am running into a issue with the y axis max value.  Here is what is happening.

I have made it so the graph can be switched between a single y axis graph and a dual y axis graph.  When doing the dual y axis graph I set mypane.yaxis.max = 100 since the values on the yaxis will never go above 100 but i don't set it for y2axis (since these values range widely).  The problem comes in when I switch from having it be a dual y axis graph to a single yaxis.  When I disable y2axis and add my curves to yaxis the yaxis.max is still set at 100 from when it was a dual yaxis.  How can I set yaxis.max back to the default so it auto scales to whatever the max value is (like how it is if you don't mess with yaxis.max).

hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to the axis scale property?

Try the following:

```
zedGraphControl.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
```

Don't forget to call `AxisChange()` to cause ZedGraph to recalculate the auto scale:

```
zedGraphControl.AxisChange();
```

Finally depending on how you are redrawing the graph, you might need:

```
zedGraphControl.GraphPane.Invalidate();
```